# Blueimp jquery file-upload. Uploading files different than images

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

Good morning.
I'm trying to use the plugin to upload some files on my server.
I set the accepted file types to odt|doc|pdf but when I try to upload a "good" file, upload fails.

I'm sure that "server/php/files" directory has 777 permision (to test it... off course).

I believe there's something wrong inside the UploadHandler.php file, because it seems created to manage only image files.

Any hint?
Thanks

Comment: So, the code for UploadHandler we should imagine, right?

Comment: Where's your code ?

Comment: Please post the contents of `UploadHandler.php` - without this we can only speculate on what the issue could be

Answer (score 0):

I've found the bug.
The "server/php" directory was not correctly addressed.
Now I have a new problem... but this is not the correct place to talk about it. In case I'll open a new post.